# Looking for the opposite of SqlGeometryBuilder: How can I decompose a SqlGeometry?

Tags: c#, sql-server, spatial, visitor-pattern, sqlgeometry

I know how to **compose a `SqlGeometry`** using `SqlGeometryBuilder`, for example:

```
// using Microsoft.SqlServer.Types;
SqlGeometryBuilder geometryBuilder = new SqlGeometryBuilder();
geometryBuilder.SetSrid(…);
geometryBuilder.BeginGeometry(OpenGisGeometryType.Polygon);
geometryBuilder.BeginFigure(0, 0);
geometryBuilder.AddLine(…);
…
geometryBuilder.EndFigure();
geometryBuilder.EndGeometry();

SqlGeometry geometry = geometryBuilder.ConstructedGeometry;
```

Once a `SqlGeometry` is built, it's pretty much an opaque object, and inspecting its constituent parts (e.g. the line segments its boundary is made up from, and those lines' end points) using the `ST…` methods methods (`STNumPoints`, `STPointN`, `STNumCurves`, `STCurveN`, `STBoundary`, etc.) feels a little cumbersome to me.

Is there something in `Microsoft.SqlServer.Types` or the .NET Framework Class Library that is the logical opposite of `SqlGeometryBuilder`, i.e. something that I could use to **decompose a `SqlGeometry`** into its constituent parts? I imagine that what I am looking for might possibly make use of the visitor pattern.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `Microsoft.SqlServer.Types` API *does* offer functionality opposite to `SqlGeometryBuilder`, in the form of [**the `SqlGeometry.Populate(IGeometrySink110)` method**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh758511.aspx).

This method accepts an object implementing [the `IGeometrySink110` interface](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sqlserver.types.igeometrysink110.aspx), whose definition very closely mirrors that of `SqlGeometryBuilder`. The method will "replay" the method calls that were used on a `SqlGeometryBuilder` in order to construct the `SqlGeometry`.

For example, given the `SqlGeometry geometry` as shown in the question above, as well as the following `IGeometrySink110` implementation:

```
class ConsoleGeometrySink : IGeometrySink110
{
    public void SetSrid(int srid)
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"SetSrid(srid: {srid})");
    }
    public void BeginGeometry(OpenGisGeometryType type)
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"BeginGeometry(type: {type})");
    }
    public void BeginFigure(double x, double y, double? z, double? m)
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"BeginFigure(x: {x}, y: {y}, z: {z}, m: {m})");
    }
    public void AddCircularArc(double x1, double y1, double? z1, double? m1,
                               double x2, double y2, double? z2, double? m2)
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"AddCircularArc(x1: {x1}, y1: {y1}, z1: {z1}, m1: {m1}, " + 
                                         $"x2: {x2}, y2: {y2}, z2: {z2}, m2: {m2})");
    }
    public void AddLine(double x, double y, double? z, double? m)
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"AddLine(x: {x}, y: {y}, z: {z}, m: {m})");
    }
    public void EndFigure()
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"EndFigure()");
    }
    public void EndGeometry()
    {
        WriteLine($"EndGeometry()");
    }
}
```

Calling `geometry.Populate(new ConsoleGeometrySink())` would output the following:

```
SetSrid(srid: …)
BeginGeometry(type: Polygon)
BeginFigure(x: 0, y: 0, z: , m: )
AddLine(…)
…
EndFigure()
EndGeometry()
```

which mirrors exactly the original steps performed to build the `SqlGeometry`.